# Vue.js re-render static content

Tags: vue.js

I'm new with Vue.js, and I notice some content re-render after changing any data that is not part of that content, here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gustavompons/rtxqhyv2/1/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <input v-model="foo1">
    <div v-html="showFoo1()"></div>
    <div v-html="showFoo2()"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2'
  },
  methods: {
    showFoo1 () {
      console.log('this is ok to execute on input')
      return this.foo1
    },
    showFoo2 () {
      console.log('this should NOT execute on input')
      return this.foo2
    }
  }
})
```

So every time I type on the input, I get "this should NOT re-render on input" in the console, which I think it's not ok because there is no reason to execute that piece of code every time.

Is this the way Vue work or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using vue.js v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of methods [are not cached](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) and will be executed every time the component is re-rendered. If you want caching and dependency tracking, use computed properties instead:

```
computed: {
  showFoo1 () {
    console.log('this is ok to execute on input')
    return this.foo1
  },
  showFoo2 () {
    console.log('this should NOT execute on input')
    return this.foo2
  }
}
```

And get rid of the `()` when accessing them.